# Using recursion to generate a list of X random numbers between 0 and 100, sorted from low to high in Python?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to write a program that uses recursion to generate a list of X random numbers within a range of 0 to 100, then sorts them from low to high. This is the code that I have written thus far:

```
import random

def multiCaller(x):
     if x == 0:
          return "Enter valid number"
     else:
          return random.randint(0, 100) + multiCaller(x)

multiCaller.sort()
return multiCaller(x)
```

This crashes, and I'm not sure where to go from here. My ideal output would look like this. Let's say I enter `multiCaller(4)`: my program would ideally generate something like `[3, 35, 45, 82]`. If I entered, `multiCaller(5)`, I would get something like `[1, 2, 45, 56, 99]`, and so on. Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Crashes how? With an `IndentationError`? Because the `def multiCaller` doesn't seem to be in the right level of indentation. Also,in `multiCaller.sort()`, the `multiCaller` should be an instance, but you are attempting to use it with a function, as far as I can see.

Comment: EDITS: Sorry, the indentation was completely screwed up at the first post. Changed to reflect proper alignment.

Comment: Iterative way: `multiCaller = lambda n: sorted([random.randint(0,100) for i in range(n)])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recursively achieve what you have said, you need to honor the base case first i.e you need to return an empty list when asked for a random number list with length zero. If x is not zero then you need to create a list with a single random number and recursively call the same function with x-1 and concatenate them both, so that it will result in a list with x number of random numbers

```
import random

def multiCaller(x):
        if x == 0:
                return []
        else:
                return [random.randint(0, 100)] + multiCaller(x-1)

def get_list(x):
    res = multiCaller(x)
    res.sort()
    return res

print get_list(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
import random

def multiCaller(x):
     if x == 0:
         return []
     else:
         result = multiCaller(x-1)
         result.append(random.randint(0, 100))
         return result

def sortedMultiCaller(x):
    result = multiCaller(x)
    result.sort()
    return result

print sortedMultiCaller(5)
```

Recursion is handled by asking for an `x-1` sized list and then adding a random integer on the end. If you ask for a 0 sized list then it just gives you an empty list. Unless this is some sort of homework problem though I would suggest just list comprehension like so:

```
import random

def multiCaller(x):
     return [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(x)]

def sortedMultiCaller(x):
    result = multiCaller(x)
    result.sort()
    return result

print sortedMultiCaller(5)
```